# Routing back with param in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

In my Angular2 project I have two pages A and B.
Page B has parameters, for example  http://localhost:4001/pageB/bw0600 has parameter `bw0600`.

When user push the button back  (<-) in the browser, he hast to be able to go to the previous page A (this works fine) and the parameters (in this case `bw0600` should be there too. So, the address of page A should look like

http://localhost:4001/pageA/bw0600

So i need maybe somehow to overwrite the usual behaviour of router back (I don't have button (just  (<-) in the browser) , so I can't write the function and bind it to element button)...

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the parameter to pageA and then forwarded them to pageB, the back button would then go to the correct, parameterized pageA.

As in: pageA => pageA/bw0600 => pageb/bw0600

You could also store the data, and then have pageA always look for the data in localstore or in a shared service when it is loaded.

Comment: Yes, when I go back from B to A is it possible to send parameters in URL from B to A?